# Какой знак поставить на месте (...)?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, знак

(Имя первого персонажа) встречает (имя второго персонажа) (...) черствого, глупого, но популярного в обществе.

Comment: Даже интересно стало, что же это за персонажи...

Answer (score 1):

Запятая или тире, но обязательно добавить слово "человека" или ему подобное:

**Иван встречает Петра, человека черствого, глупого, но популярного в обществе.**

**Иван встречает Петра - человека черствого, глупого, но популярного в обществе.**

Comment: В "человеке" нет необходимости, имхо. Да и не всегда прокатывает.  "Баба Яга встречает Кощея...". Не стоило бы о том упоминать, но добавление родового наименования может изменить грамматику фразы (с приложения на уточнение) и опосредовано сказаться на выбор пунктуационного оформления.

Comment: А вдруг там не Кощей, а помещик Пустяков? Откуда вам знать, участник @Мимоходов?
*Не стоило бы о том упоминать* -- это верно. Продолжение фразы очень заумное, а содержание ну очень сомнительное. Имхо, конечно, имхо.

Answer (score 0):

Тире или запятая, как уже сказали, необходимы. Скорее тире (если никаких "человеков" не добавлять), но сильно зависит от авторского контекста.

Answer (score -1):

Тире, а не запятая. Это объяснение.